# Should factory objects be persisted? Mine are for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am defining my factories using factory_girl like this:

```
Factory.define :user do |u| 

u.name "blah"
u.age 22


end
```

And they are saved to the db, is this good practise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's good practice:

- if your tests need a saved object
- if your tests don't need a persisted object, you can simply call `Factory.build`
- to clean your db between tests, consider using the `DatabaseCleaner` gem
- other alternatives are: `Factory.stub` and `Factory.attributes_for`